# How to make slide move auto after the page is clicked?

Tags: jquery, easyslider

I use http://cssglobe.com/lab/easyslider1.7/02.html plugin for slide show.
But when i click on the page, the slide stops to move automatic.

```
$("#slider").easySlider({
        auto: true, 
        speed: 800,
        pause: 5000,
        continuous: true,
        numeric: true,
        prevText:       'Previous',
        nextText:       'Next'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for some javascript error on you page, this should be the reason the script stoped work.

Many times javascript problems stop script execution

Comment: If you go by link that I post, the same problem occurs there, is it bug?

Comment: hmm i doesn't undestand initial question, on this case its a behavior, when you click it stop on page and stop slide.

Comment: @user2322509 to do what you expect you need to set auto: true and pause: the time you want to wait. Set less time on pause and test if he start sliding again. Let me know if no.